# Mongodb sort with id examine all the records?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to analyze the following query performance. Executing the query with 50k entries in a collection it takes 23 sec to respond.

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({ipAddress: "127.0.0.1"}).sort({"_id": -1})
```

In this query ipAddress is indexed and id is indexed by default. I checked with explain command and the response is

```
"totalKeysExamined" : 49827,
"totalDocsExamined" : 49827,
```

But when i removed the sorting and the response is

```
"totalKeysExamined" : 23877,
"totalDocsExamined" : 23877,
```

I would like to know Mongodb sort with id examine all the records?

**EDITED:**

Adding the entire response of explain query

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "collection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "ipAddress" : {
            "$eq" : "127.0.0.1"
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "ipAddress" : {
                "$eq" : "127.0.0.1"
            }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "_id_",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : true,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "backward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "_id" : [ 
                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ 
        {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : -1.0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "ipAddress" : 1.0
                        },
                        "indexName" : "ipAddress_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "ipAddress" : [ 
                                "[\"127.0.0.1\", \"127.0.0.1\"]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 33809,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 25572,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 105260,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 105260,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "ipAddress" : {
                "$eq" : "127.0.0.1"
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : 33809,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 24894,
        "works" : 105261,
        "advanced" : 33809,
        "needTime" : 71451,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 1376,
        "restoreState" : 1376,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "docsExamined" : 105260,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned" : 105260,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2020,
            "works" : 105261,
            "advanced" : 105260,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 1376,
            "restoreState" : 1376,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "keyPattern" : {
                "_id" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "_id_",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "isUnique" : true,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "backward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "_id" : [ 
                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined" : 105260,
            "dupsTested" : 0,
            "dupsDropped" : 0,
            "seenInvalidated" : 0
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "client",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.2.16",
    "gitVersion" : "1"
},
"ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: It would be simple to answer if you add the rest of the explain output. I **guess** it uses different indexes.  Apparently filtering by ip index and doing in-memory sort is more expensive than fetching everything already sorted by _id and applying filter afterwards considering half of the collection matches the filter.

Comment: @AlexBlex sorry for the late response. I have added the entire response in the edited section.

Comment: It seems the db has grown up a bit since then =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/3 of your collection matches the filter `{ipAddress: "127.0.0.1"}`.

It is quicker to fetch all 100k the documents in the correct order

`"stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : {"_id" : 1}`

and then filter out the ones that don't match:

`"stage" : "FETCH", "filter" : {"ipAddress" : {"$eq" : "127.0.0.1"}}`

rather than fetch by filter

`"stage" : "IXSCAN", "keyPattern" : {"ipAddress" : 1.0}`

and then sort 40k documents in memory

`"stage" : "SORT","sortPattern" : {"_id" : -1.0}`

When you remove sorting, it is quicker to use the `{"ipAddress" : 1.0}` index to fetch only matched documents.

You may find an index `{ipAddress: 1, _id: 1}` more efficient, specially if you combine it with same projection option.

As a side note, it doesn't look quite healthy.  I can imagine the FETCH stage so slow because of heavy documents being loaded from disk, swapped back, et. But I see no valid reason why the IXSCAN stage

```
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned" : 105260,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2020,
```

takes more than 2s. IXSCAN of 100k _ids should be 10 times quicker.